# Calling a member function of an inherited vector element

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I am working on a simulation of sorts where there is a player in a 2D world of blocks. The many block objects are stored in a vector, and each has a member that is a reference to this vector, so that each may iterate through the others in order to handle things like collisions. To simplify the player's physics with the blocks, I have made the Player class inherit from the Block class. While this does make the physics much simpler, I have run into the issue of the inability to call a player member function while referring to the player from the vector.

Here are some simplified versions of the classes:

```
class Block{
private:
    std::vector<Block>& blocks;
public:
    Block(std::vector<Block>& b) : blocks(b) {}
};

class Player : public virtual Block{
public:
    Player(std::vector<Block>& b) : Block(b) {}
    void player_only_function();
};

std::vector<Block> blocks;
Player player(blocks);
blocks.push_back(player);

blocks[0].player_only_function(); // This line in incorrect
```

Is there a simple way to get around this?

Comment: *"I have made the Player class inherit from the Block class"* - That does not sound right. Public inheritance models an IS-A relationship, and a player is not a block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible if you only have a vector of `Block` objects, and then you have *object slicing* when toy push back your `Player` object.

Instead you have to use pointers and something called *downcasting*. Like

```
std::vector<Block*> blocks;
blocks.push_back(new Player(blocks));

static_cast<Player*>(blocks[0])->player_only_function();
```

However, you have to be careful that the downcast you make is actually valid, and that `blocks[0]` is a pointer to a `Player` object.

Comment: I see. If I make `blocks` a vector of `Block*`s, and do `blocks.push_back(&player)`, can I then simply call `player.player_only_function()` instead of casting?

Comment: @KaiSchmidt Think a little bit about what you just wrote, calling `player_only_function` on the `player` object will always be possible. :) If you want to use pointers to the base class then you need to cast. However, pushing back `&player` you need to think about the lifetime of `player`. If  `player` gets destructed before you use the pointer then the pointer is not longer valid.

Comment: Having to downcast like this actually, more often than not, defeats the point of having a class hierarchy (i.e. a base class and derived classes).   Look up ways of providing required functions (e.g. pure virtuals) in the base class, and exploit polymorphism instead.